# EXTRA_MESSAGE and putExtra()

Tags: android

I am following the Building Your First Application on Android Developers. I built an intent for a button to send a message from a editText to a new activity. Problem is with EXTRA_MESSAGE and activity_display_message. When I want to run the program the following errors occurs:

```
Error:(21, 53) error: cannot find symbol variable activity_display_message
Error:(36, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable EXTRA_MESSAGE
```

how can I resolve it?

[image]

Comment: You have not declared EXTRA_MESSAGE variable as public static in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("YourValueKey", yourData.getText().toString());
```

then you can get it from your second activity by :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String YourtransferredData = intent.getExtras().getString("YourValueKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the MainActivity, put this line

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.holidayProject.MESSAGE";
```

Note: This line is put just before the first `@override` upon the start of the MainActivity class like this:

[image: Example code]